# Multiple EditText in ListView with ArrayAdapter fails to get text after user entry

Tags: android, android-edittext, listview-adapter

I have implemented a ListView (multiple rows with 2 EditText, currently fixed 2 rows).when user enters data in EditText in both the rows, I want to display the data entered by user as Toast message like below:

[image]

The code which I used, is below:
main xml (activity_main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.listviewtest.MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonDisp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDisp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Display Data" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter layout xml(list_view_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idNum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.25"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Num"
    android:minWidth="80dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idID"
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="ID"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:minWidth="50dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity class (Observe function OnDispButClick() where Toast is implemented):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private int m_nNumOfRows = 3;
private MyDatabase[] m_myDatabase;
private ListView m_listview;//
private ArrayAdapterItem m_myDatabaseAdapterItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    initAdapter();
    OnDispButClick();
}

// Class where Toast is handled
private void OnDispButClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button dispBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDisp);
    dispBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonDisp) {
                // Display
                String strDisplay = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < m_nNumOfRows; i++) {
                    strDisplay += m_myDatabase[i].getNum()
                            + m_myDatabase[i].getID();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDisplay,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    m_nNumOfRows = 2;
    m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
}

private void initAdapter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    m_myDatabase = new MyDatabase[m_nNumOfRows];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nNumOfRows; i++) {
        m_myDatabase[i] = new MyDatabase("", "");
    }

    m_myDatabaseAdapterItem = new ArrayAdapterItem(this,
            R.layout.list_view_layout, m_myDatabase);
    m_listview.setAdapter(m_myDatabaseAdapterItem);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ArrayAdapter File:

```
public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<MyDatabase> {

Context mContext;
int layoutResourceId;
MyDatabase data[] = null;

public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId,
        MyDatabase[] data) {

    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    final MyDatabase MyDatabase = data[position];
    if (convertView == null) {

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.editTextId = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.idID);
        holder.editTextNum = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.idNum);
        holder.editTextId.setText(MyDatabase.getID());
        holder.editTextNum.setText(MyDatabase.getNum());
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.editTextId = viewHolder.editTextId;
        holder.editTextNum = viewHolder.editTextNum;
        holder.editTextId.setText(MyDatabase.getID());
        holder.editTextNum.setText(MyDatabase.getNum());

    }

    holder.editTextNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyDatabase.setNum(s.toString());
        }
    });

    holder.editTextId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyDatabase.setID(s.toString());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    EditText editTextNum;
    EditText editTextId;
};
}
```

My Database which has to be updated whenever user enters data in editText of ListView which is implemented using ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyDatabase  implements Comparable<MyDatabase>
{

private String m_strNum;
private String m_strID;

public MyDatabase(String strNum,String strID) {
    m_strNum = strNum;
    m_strID = strID;
}

public void setData(String strNum,String strID)
{
    m_strNum = strNum;
    m_strID = strID;
}

public void setNum(String strNum)
{
    m_strNum = strNum;
}

public void setID(String strID)
{
    m_strID = strID;
}

public String getNum()
{
    return m_strNum;
}

public String getID()
{
    return m_strID;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(MyDatabase another) {
    return 1;
}
}
```

Whenever user press the button "DisplayData", ultimately I want to update the MyDatabaseClass array based on the EditBox data in Listview.

Please help me to fix this. Also kindly let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line, when you want to display the content of the EditText's in the `Toast`:

```
strDisplay += m_myDatabase[i].getID()
                    + m_myDatabase[i].getID();
```

You display your `ID` twice, when in your adapter you set such fields as `ID` and `Num`. I think it should be:

```
strDisplay += m_myDatabase[i].getID()
                    + m_myDatabase[i].getNum();
```

Comment: Yes, There was a mistake. I have fixed that. However, the issue is not yet fixed

Comment: plz help me to fix this.